# Mask URL of all subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess

My task is pretty straight forward, I need to mask / hide the url of all the sub-directories under a folder.

For example lets suppose my website is www.captainabc.com/test. I want to mask all the sub-directories under test. So whether someone types in: www.captainabc.com/test/123, www.captainabc.com/test/ABC, or www.captainabc.com/test/Example, etc... The address bar should read www.captainabc.com/test/Mypage while displaying the content of the requested url.

Essentially I want to hide the name of any sub-directory under the test folder and have the browser address bar show Mypage instead.

I understand that this can be accomplished via Rewrite rules in the .htaccess file. I tried using the below with a couple of changes, but since this is my first time using this concept I didn't really know how to get it to work :(

```
RewriteEngine on
# check that the request url is neither a file nor a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Any hints will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You want to `redirect` all subdirectories to /test/Mypage when they type any subdirectory?

Comment: @PanamaJack No I want to keep the URL being requested but in the browser address bar swap their requested page's url to /Mypage to hide the original one. Not sure if this makes sense but I am trying to not expose the page name but rather mask it. Appreciate if you can point me in the write direction :)

Comment: Doesn't really make sense. if they request `/test/somepage/` then they already know the url. I guess I don't get what you're trying to do.

Comment: @PanamaJack Actually there is a login form on my page, where the user is prompted to enter the username given to him. On clicking "OK" the form redirects the user to www.captainabc.com/test/**username**. Now I don't want the user to know that this is the url he has been taken to is his username as this will give him the idea that he can just swap the name in the url and get access to other's people's pages. So instead I would like him to be taken to that page but so that the address bar will display **MyPage** instead of his name.

Comment: @PanamaJack Hope this make more sense now, sorry for leaving out that part earlier.

Comment: You can't do this with htaccess, you need to redesign your site or use a different framework.

Comment: @JonLin Thanks for the tip. What exactly means different framework. Anything particular you can suggest?

Comment: You want the URL to look one way when the content is somewhere else, so that page is going to have to magically know where to serve the content, I don't have anything I can suggest that will do something like that but it's clear the scope of the issue goes far, far beyond hiding a URL from the browser